# AngularJS- button not displaying on widget 'toolbar'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, widget

I have an angularJS app, and on one of the pages, there are a number of widgets displayed. When the user click a 'Settings' button on that page (the button is separate to the widgets), the 'toolbar' for each widget is displayed on the widgets, with a number of buttons on each one (different buttons depending on which widget the toolbar belongs to).

I am currently trying to add a new button to the widget toolbars, which would take the user to the relevant page that each widget is showing information from.

The `directive` in which the widgets' HTML is rendered is:

```
.directive('umwWizard', function($q, $route, $modal, $timeout, $compile, ultUI,
                             umWidget, DialogMgr) {
    var wizardTmpl = '<section ng-click="addWidget($event)" ' +
    'class="glyphicon-clickable"><div data-ng-hide="swapTo != undefined">' +
    '<span class="ti-widget"></span><p data-i18n="Click to add an item">' +
    '</p></div></section>';

// Overlay editing panel template
var editPanelTmpl = '<div class="widget-preview-edit-panel">' +
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer glyphicon-clickable" ' +
    'data-ng-click="toggleSwapMode()" ' +
    'data-ng-hide="!swap() || swapTo != undefined"></span>' +
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog glyphicon-clickable" ' +
    'data-ng-click="editWidget()" ' +
    'data-ng-hide="swapMode || swapTo != undefined"></span>' +
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove glyphicon-clickable"' +
    ' data-ng-click="deleteWidget()" ' +
    'data-ng-hide="swapMode || swapTo != undefined"></span></div>'; /* +
    /*ERF(28/07/2017 @ 1030) Add 'naviateToPage' button to the widget toolbar
    '<span class="ti-layers" ' +
    'data-ng-click="goToWidgetRoot()" ' +
    'data-ng-hide="swapMode || swapTo != undefined"></span></div>'; */

// Swap me button template
var swapMeBtnTmpl = '<button type="button" data-ng-click="swapMe()" ' +
    'class="btn btn-sm btn-w-sm btn-gap-v btn-round wiz-swap-me" ' +
    'data-ng-show="swapTo != undefined"><span data-i18n="Swap with me" ' +
    'data-ng-show="swapTo != region"></span><span data-i18n="Cancel" ' +
    'data-ng-show="swapTo == region"></span></button>';




return {
    restrict: 'E',
        // functions defined here
        ...
})
```

When I 'inspect' the toolbar element of one of the widgets when viewing the page in a browser, I can see that the toolbar icons are displayed by the section underneath the comment:

> Overlay editing panel template.

I tried adding in the markup for the button that I want to add to the widget toolbar:

```
'<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-more-windows">' +
'data-ng-click="goToWidgetRoot()" ' +
'data-ng-hide="swapMode || swapTo != undefined"></span>' +
```

But for some reason, when I now view the page in the browser, the button that I've added to the widget toolbar is not displayed.

When I 'inspect' the toolbar in the browser, I can see the markup for the other buttons that were already there, but can't see the markup for the button that I've added...

Can anyone tell me why this is? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if your copypaste of the snippet for the button being added is accurate to what you intended to put on here, but it looks like you're closing the span prematurely in the first line.

It looks like it should be:

```
'<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-more-windows" ' +
'data-ng-click="goToWidgetRoot()" ' +
'data-ng-hide="swapMode || swapTo != undefined"></span>' +
```

Comment: You're right, I was closing the span prematurely, however, I've fixed that, but am still having the same issue with the button not being displayed...

Comment: @someone2088 just in case you haven't changed it in your actual code, your edit to your main post is still wrong. The '>' at the end of the first line should not be there, because it appears on the third line. Just making sure you didn't do the same thing in the actual code!